# Jquery detect the end of effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I created simple function for rotate divs , for this i use setTimeOut and this function tell the script the time for repit the same and go to the next , the problem in my case is i use effects in each transitions and need the callback to the function happend to the end of effect

**My function :**

```
<script>
function repiter(id)
{

$(".sd_"+id).show(2000).hide(1000);

var npics=4;
var ret=(id+1);


if (ret>=npics)
{
var ret=0;  
}

setTimeout(function(){repiter(ret);},2000)  

}
</script>


<div class="sd_0" style="display:none;">Tester 1</div>
<div class="sd_1" style="display:none;">Tester 2</div>
<div class="sd_2" style="display:none;">Tester 3</div>
<div class="sd_3" style="display:none;">Tester 4</div>

<script>
repiter(0);
</script>
```

As you can see here , the function rotate the 4 divs and the contents , when go to the end repit the first and all time return , but in each case , the effect for each div = 4 or 5 seconds and in middle of animation of div the setTimeout call other time the function and break the effect in each case , by this my question , exists some method in jquery for setTimeout only run when effects it´s finished and after this call other time to the function ?

Thank´s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/):

```
$(".sd_"+id).show(2000).hide(1000).promise().done(function() {
    // now the animations are done
});
```

Comment: Can you put me this inside my function for see all right , thank´s for shared and help me , regards

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script> 
    function repiter(id) {

    $(".sd_"+id).show(2000, function(){
    $(".sd_"+id).hide(1000, function(){

    var npics=4; var ret=(id+1);

    if(ret>=npics) { var ret=0; }

setTimeout(function(){repiter(ret);},2000)
})
})


} </script>
```